# How Do I Get rid of Windows and having Ubuntu as main OS

Tags: installation, windows

I have used Ubuntu exclusively now for the past year. I installed it with wubi. I now want to get rid of windows and have just Ubuntu. Cant this be done easily?

Answer (score 2):

I would backup my files and make a clean install.
*Backup your hidden files in the home folder (they begin with a dot e.g. `.mozilla`) and copy them onto the new installed home folder to keep your current settings/profiles.*